# Form in Internet Explorer always posting

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, internet-explorer, post

I wonder why `Internet Explorer` (any version) always gives `POST` without calling the right `function` `onSubmit`. Works only if i `refresh` the page

Forms' content is generated dynamically by `PHP/MySQL` here:

```
<form id="formQtd" name="formQtd" onSubmit="return validaQtd();" method="post">
        <p class="cab">Por favor informe a quantidade de Ovos de P&aacute;scoa em estoque em sua loja neste momento:</p>
        <div id="produtos">
            <?
                if ($linhas2 == 0)
                    echo "<p style='margin-left: 15px'>A pesquisa foi cancelada pelo administrador</p>";
                else {
                    if ($linhas == 0)
                        echo "<p style='margin-left: 15px'>Nenhum ovo de p&aacute;scoa cadastrado</p>";
                    else {
                        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                            $texto = "<div id='thumb'>
                            ";
                                $texto .= "<img width='100' height='100' src='img_pan/".$row["imagem"]."' />
                                ";
                                $texto .= "<p id='pNome'>".utf8_encode($row["nome"])."</p>
                                ";
                                $texto .= " <input type='text' value='' class='inputQtd num' name='".$row["id"]."_prod' id='qtd$row[id]' placeholder='Quant.' /> 
                                ";
                                $texto .= "</div>";
                                echo $texto;
                        }?>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submitQtd" value="Enviar" style="width:70px;height:25px;clear:both;float:right;border:1px solid #873305; background-color:#300300; color:white; margin:5px 0px 20px 0px" />
    </form>  
    <?
                            }
                }
    ?>
```

My `function` validaQtd:

```
function validaQtd() { 
  var inp = document.forms[0].getElementsByTagName('input');
  console.log(inp.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < inp.length; i++){
    if(inp[i].type == "text"){
        if(inp[i].value == ""){
            console.log(inp[i].value+" - "+inp[i].id);
            alert('Preencha as quantidades em branco');
            inp[i].focus();
            return false;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

My `POST`:

```
if ($_POST) {

    $time = microtime(true);
    $micro_time = sprintf("%06d",($time - floor($time)) * 1000000);
    $date = new DateTime( date('Y-m-d H:i:s.'.$micro_time,$time) );
    $dt = $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s.u");
    $dtAtual = substr($dt, 0, -3);

    $upload = 0;                
    foreach ( $_POST as $nome => $valor ) {
        if($nome != "submit" && $valor != "") {
            $upload = 1;
            //separando o codigo do nome
            $prov = explode("_", $nome);
            $cdProd = str_replace("_","",$prov[0]); 

            //inserindo no banco    
            $queryIns = "INSERT INTO registro_ovos2013 (idusuario, idproduto, quantidade, data) VALUES ('".$cdUsu."', ".$cdProd.", ".$valor.", '".$dtAtual."')";
            $resultIns = mysql_query($queryIns);
        }   
    }
    if ($upload == 1) {
        ?>
        <script>
            alert("Quantidade cadastrada!");                        
            window.location = "?codigo=<?=$cdUsu;?>";
        </script>
        <?
    } 
    else {
        ?>
        <script>
            alert("Preencha os campos em branco");                      
            window.location = "?codigo=<?=$cdUsu;?>";
        </script>
        <?
    }
}
```

Comment: What you're doing here is extremely dangerous because you're not doing any [SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/). You should be very careful to escape any and all values that will be put into your queries. The best way to do this is to use [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and [SQL placeholders](http://bobby-tables.com/php).

Comment: Hm.. this is a extranet page, but ok, you're right. I'll check.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean that your steps are like this:

- Load a page.
- Enter valid data.
- Submit (function is called)
- Reload (POST processed, validating function not called)

If yes, that is quite normal. Page is loaded with some POST request and reloading it causes requesting again. And no javascript is involved.

That is why you always need to validate data on the server-side too. Right after `if ($_POST) {`

Comment: No, Alex. The page loads, I don't fill anything. I submit and no function is called.

Comment: The same that your JS function `validaQtd()` does. It should be done anyway for sake of security. And more important is SQL escaping that is mentioned in the comments to the question.

Comment: Hm.. I understood. SQL Escaping is ok, i checked and edited... Really, do you understand why occurs this? only IE ignores..

Comment: Yes, @AlexZam. Without success. I validate the website on W3C. Still in trouble.

Answer (score 0):

If your page is parsed as XML (as XHTML), you should use `onsubmit` as the attribute's name (instead of `onSubmit`). XML is case sensitive.